# Creating the listset of data from array of MySql query result

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to create the list of products in box-style based on the data loaded from the database. I am using mysqli for querying the result and here is my code

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'shop');
$result = $db->query('select * from products');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
?>
```

With this code, I got a multi-dimensional array that contains the information of all products in the database and I want to use this data to create the list of products like this code

```
<div class='each-product'>
    <div class='img'>
        <img src="images/xxx.jpg" />
    </div>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
    <h3>PRICE</h3>
</div>
```

I used to use this code for iteration but the foreach() did not return the expected result

```
<?php
foreach($data as $product) {
    echo "<div class='each-product'>";
        echo "<div class='img'>";
            echo "<img src='images/".$product['image']."' />";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<h2>".$product['title']."</h2>";
        echo "<h3>".$product['price']."</h3>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

When I run this code, it returned nothing on the screen. It is currently not solved.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($data)` to see if your DB loop actually did anything? you're just ASSUMING the query succeeded, which is never a good thing. There's exactly ONE way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Always assume failure, check for that failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: `return $data;` Is that code being run in a function? What is the relation between the PHP code at the top of your question and the PHP code at the bottom? Are they in the same file?

Comment: Yepp! That's inside the method in Model part. Sorry for the mistake. This is not in the same file, the method is in the Model part and the $data array is sent to the controller then to the view. I can successfully parse the $data to the view but I don't know to iterate because the $data is a multidimensional array. If I used nested foreach(). The outer foreach() iterates through each product and the inner foreach() will not product the expected column order.